# Не работает formIt

Tags: php, modx

Ребят, всем привет. Возникла такая проблема, formIt не отправляет и не сохраняет формы. Отправляю все и пишет «Форма отправлена», после смотрю — не где нечего нет, не в FormIt не на почте. В логах одна ошибка PHP Deprecated: Unparenthesized `a? b: c? d: e` is deprecated. Use either `(a? b: c)? d: e` or `a? b: (c? d: e)` in /var/www/vladisla/data/www/vladislavchumak.com.ua/core/model/modx/modx.class.php on line 678\n, referer: vladislavchumak.com.ua/manager/?, как исправить это дело?? Подскажите пожалуйста, уже второй день сижу над ней. Вызов сниппета:

```html
[[!AjaxForm?
&snipper=`FormIt`
&form=`@FILE chunks/contact-form.tpl`
&hooks=`email,FormItSaveForm`
&formName=`Обратная связь`
&formFields=`name,email,message`
&fieldNames=`name==Имя,email==Почта,message==Сообщение`
&emailTpl=`@FILE chunks/email.tpl`
&validate=`name:required,email:email:required,message:required`
&emailTo=`[[++send-email]]`
&emailFrom=`web@vladislavchumak.com.ua`
&emailSubject=`Форма обратной связи с [[++site_name]] (Блок контакты)`
&emailFromName=`[[++site_name]]`
]]
```

Comment: Альтернативно попробуйте отправить письмо через https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/quickemail/index, что он пишет?включите дебаг

[[!QuickEmail? &debug=`1`]]

Comment: @AntonTarasov SYSTEM SETTINGS (USED IF PROPERTY IS MISSING):
emailsender System Setting: web@vladislavchumak.com.ua
site_name System Setting: Chumak
PROPERTIES (FROM PARAMETERS, PROPERTY SET, OR SNIPPET DEFAULT PROPERTIES:
Tpl chunk name:
subject:
to:
fromName:
replyTo:
emailSender:
allowHtml: 1
message:
FINAL VALUES (ACTUALLY USED WHEN SENDING EMAIL):
subject: Default Subject
to: web@vladislavchumak.com.ua
fromName: QuickEmail
replyTo: web@vladislavchumak.com.ua
emailSender: web@vladislavchumak.com.ua
allowHtml: 1
Message Body: Default Message
SEND REPORTED SUCCESSFUL